# Google Street View Marker Scale

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

When I click and drag my custom marker within street view the marker scales to account for depth. This is great but causes issues with what I am trying to achieve. Is there any way to disable it? I have searched everywhere for a boolean option or something but haven't found one yet. I am currently trying to override the scaling with my own code and tried setting that marker to:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1) !important;
```

without any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.